# loop through json string via java script

Tags: jquery, json

I have retrieved data from database and parsed it like this javascript

```
var categories = <?php echo json_encode($categories); ?>;
```

in source code categories variable has following values:

```
var categories = [{"id":"27","name":"john"},{"id":"8","name":"jack"}]
```

now I'm trying to loop through this array like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert(categories);
cats = jQuery.parseJSON(categories);

for (x in cats)
{
    alert(cats.name);
}
}
```

but I'm getting nothing. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (x in categories)
    {
        alert(categories[x].name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using `json_encode` what you are actually creating is a Javascript object.  (JSON is a string that represents a Javascript object.)  Since JSON syntax is valid Javascript syntax, this works fine.

Just remove the call to `jQuery.parseJSON` and loop through `categories` directly.

Answer (score 0):

here is another working example, copy paste and try...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var categories = ['{ "id": "27", "name": "john" }', '{ "id": "8", "name": "jack"}'];
        for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            var c = jQuery.parseJSON(categories[i])
            alert(c.name);
        }
    });
```